# Upcounting output

Tags: python, output

I've a problem and I have no idea how to solve it.

Well, I've written a small Python program. It calculates a number and then should output another number. E.g. when the solution is below 100 it should print '100m', when it's <200 it should print '101m', <300 = '102m' etc...

I could write something like

```
if solution < 100:
  print '100m'
elif solution < 200:
  print '101m'
elif solution < 300:
  print '102m'
```

Would be possible BUT I think it's impossible to do that again and again until 1000 or 2000 and it would look weird in the code. ;-)

Hope there is an answer... (Oh and sorry for my bad English and Python knowledge)

Comment: Maybe I am just missing something obvious, but what would you want the output to be for e.g. `2000` -> "120m" or "1020m"?

Comment: "120m"!! Sorry for forgetting that, I just saw the mistake. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
print("10{}m".format(x//100))
```

(You really just want to divide by 100 and round down.)

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work for me. It can't assign to function the call... Do I need a library? And my answer is called "distance". I have to exchange with the "x", don't I?

Comment: Maybe it's because I am running Python2, but aren't you missing a formatting index in that expression?
`print("10{0}m".format(x//100))` - and if I use this version it will not produce the same output as posted - for `x=100` this would output `101m`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I made a mistake in the lines before. :D

Comment: @Gjallar no, `{}` is a valid format string in Python 2 (try it). And for `x=100` the OP wants `101m`, because `100 < 100` is false.

Comment: @Gjallar The positional argument specifiers can be omitted from Python 2.7+

Comment: @Paolo ah that explains my problem - my cygwin is a bit outdated and runs python 2.6

Comment: Well, I hope someone will read this: If the solution is bigger than 1000, (e.g. 3600) it prints 1036 instead of 113. Any idea? I know that in this case you can't divide it through 100 and put it after "10", because the 0 is in the wrong place. Also, if it's like 36000 it won't print it right...

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 100; round down. That number is the last digit in your examples.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to increment the printed number by 1 for every step of 100 that the solution variable takes?

If so you could calculate the the addend easily:

```
addend = (solution / 100)
print str(100 + addend) + "m"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic reads to me as:

```
print solution / 100 + 100
```